# ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE | Can't get past SAVE/DELETE menu

Tags: java, android, photo

First of, this is not a duplicate, I've seen similar posts but with no good answers. Now, this is the menu I'm talking about:

[image: screenshot]

This only happens in some devices, in my particular Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo, it does well, and everything that it's supposed to, but on a friend of mines Wiko (French brand, but pretty good), aswell as on the emulator above, it just does nothing when I click on "save". Here is my code if you could take a look:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
imageFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), path);

Uri tempuri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, tempuri);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

If you need any more details tell me  :)

Comment: Perhaps that device has a buggy camera app, one that does not handle `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` properly.

Comment: Idk man, it doesn't work on the emulator either :/

Comment: What is the value of `path`?

Comment: @greenapps `public String imgName = "goQuiz/profilePic.jpg";`

Comment: I do not see an imageFile.getParentFile().exists() in your code before opening the intent.

Comment: `when I click on "save"`. That i don't see either.

Comment: @greenapps Did you see the image that i uploaded on tinypic? It isn't "save" per say on this phone, on this case it's the "right" symbol.